# How can I position my marquee from the bottom left of my image?

Tags: photoshop

I have a timestamp that's in the bottom left of every photo from a bad export from a long time ago. I want to remove them, which works perfectly by selecting the area with the marquee and going up to edit -> fill -> content aware. Awesome!

The problem is I have to do this with 10,000 images. So, with some Googling, I learned how to create a Photoshop Action by recording the above tasks and then I went to file -> automate, selected my folder, and it worked. Awesome!

For a minute, until I realized that not all of my images are the same height, and Photoshop is basing my actions from the *top* of the photo, not the bottom. If I could position my marquee based on the x,y of the bottom left of my image, I would be good to go, but I don't see how to do this.

Comment: Ps has a ruler offset (top/bottom/center, left/right/center) - I'm not sure if actions use that information or not.  Might be worth investigating...

Comment: If you're on *nix (don't know about windows) take a look at imagemagick. I believe the composite command will help. Then with a quick four line script you can have them all done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a step in the action to rotate the image 90 degrees clockwise, then place the marquee in the top left, apply the fill, then rotate by 90 degrees anticlockwise.

Comment: 90 degrees, surely? He needs to make the bottom left corner move to the top left, which is 90 degrees clockwise

Comment: @NickM yes, you're absolutely right there, for some reason I was thinking it needed to be placed in bottom right...

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly that and it worked. I went with one turn clockwise and it put it right where I needed it.